# Selenium script that books a room

Tags: python, beginner, selenium

I have a lot to learn in Python, and now I am adventuring in automating tasks with Selenium. Specifically, to just quickly explain the purpose of the script I have created, I have made a script that books a room at my school that I use to study in. Rather than doing this manually I figured this could easily have been done by a script.

My script works, and I use it with windows run scheduler so that it starts automatically, but it is awfully written. The problem is I don't know what I should improve, so I'm coming here hoping that someone can help me on what I can change in my code to make it better.

Ideas that I have myself:

- I would really like to remove my time.sleeps in the code, so that python recognizes when the request is completed and then continues to the next step in the code rather than waiting for a fixed amount of time.

All advice is appreciated! Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import re
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date
import calendar

#You can skip this part and read from the function
now = datetime.datetime.now()
day_name = now.strftime("%A")

l = {"Monday" : 1, "Tuesday" : 2, "Wednesday" : 3, "Thursday" : 4, "Friday" : 5, "Saturday" : 6, "Sunday" : 7}
n = l[day_name]


Date = date.today()
EndDate = Date + timedelta(days=10)

print(Date)

date_DD = str(Date)[8:11]
date_DD_even = int(date_DD) % 2

def login():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

    browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver directory", chrome_options = options)
    browser.get('website')

    time.sleep(1)

    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#logincontrol > a.items.itemsbox')
    navigate.click()

    time.sleep(1)

    #user + password
    if date_DD_even == 0:
        user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#userNameInput')
        user.send_keys('user')
        password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#passwordInput')
        password.send_keys('password')

    time.sleep(3)

    login = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#submitButton')
    login.click()

    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#contents > div.linklist > div > div > a > div > span.lightlink > span')
    navigate.click()

    time.sleep(1)


    ###Choose date to book
    date_to_book = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#leftresdate')
    text_area = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#leftresdate').clear()
    date_to_book.send_keys(str(EndDate))
    date_to_book.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(3)

    #Open Schedule
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#objectselectionresult > table > tbody > tr.resetObjectExpand.eo13348.clickable > td.expname.nw')
    navigate.click()

    time.sleep(3)


    #Choose day to book
    if (n != 1 and n != 2):
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        day_to_book = (n+5)%7
        time.sleep(2)
        if (day_to_book == 1):
            navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#objectselectionresult > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > div.weekContainer > div:nth-child(1) > div.weekDiv > div.slotfree2.slotfreetarget')
            navigate.click()
        if (day_to_book == 2):
            navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#objectselectionresult > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > div.weekContainer > div:nth-child(2) > div.weekDiv > div.slotfree2.slotfreetarget')
            navigate.click()
        if (day_to_book == 3):
            navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#objectselectionresult > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > div.weekContainer > div:nth-child(3) > div.weekDiv > div.slotfree2.slotfreetarget')
            navigate.click()
        if (day_to_book == 4):
            navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#objectselectionresult > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > div.weekContainer > div:nth-child(4) > div.weekDiv > div.slotfree2.slotfreetarget')
            navigate.click()                                
        if (day_to_book == 5):
            navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#objectselectionresult > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > div.weekContainer > div:nth-child(5) > div.weekDiv > div.slotfree2.slotfreetarget')
            navigate.click()
        if (day_to_book == 6):
            pass
        if (day_to_book == 7):
            pass
    else:
        browser.quit()


    #Choose time to book
    time.sleep(3)
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#newResTimeDiv > tbody > tr > td.first > select.ui-widget.ui-state-default.timedrop.timeHourStart2 > option:nth-child(11)')
    navigate.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#newResTimeDiv > tbody > tr > td.first > select.ui-widget.ui-state-default.timedrop.timeMinuteStart2 > option:nth-child(1)')
    navigate.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#newResTimeDiv > tbody > tr > td.second > select.ui-widget.ui-state-default.timedrop.timeHourEnd2 > option:nth-child(18)')
    navigate.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#newResTimeDiv > tbody > tr > td.second > select.ui-widget.ui-state-default.timedrop.timeMinuteEnd2 > option:nth-child(3)')
    navigate.click()

    #Press OK after choosing times

    time.sleep(2)
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#newResTimeDiv > tbody > tr > td.third > input')
    navigate.click()

    #Details of booking
    time.sleep(3)
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#leftreswrap > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > span > span')
    navigate.click()

    time.sleep(3)

    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#info0 > div.infoboxtitle')
    navigate.click()

    time.sleep(3)

    #Press OK to book
    navigate = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#continueRes2')
    navigate.click()

    time.sleep(2)

    text = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="resmadetoptext"]').text
    print(text)
    text = MIMEText(text)
    time.sleep(2)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = "subject"
    msg['From'] = "sender"
    msg.attach(text)

    mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.login("email", "email-pass")
    mail.sendmail("sender", "recipient", msg.as_string())
    print("email sent")
    mail.close()
    browser.quit()

login()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems right off the bat; others may present themselves after the first round of refactoring.

1. You've got too much code in the `login()` function. Functions ought to be 20 lines or less so they can be perceived with one glance. Create multiple  functions, each of which has one job per the [single responsibility principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
2. Use a main guard so that `login()` is not called unconditionally upon loading the file. Just one extra line:

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       login()
   ```

   (though again, this `main()` function should consist almost entirely of calling other functions). This allows using the source as a library without having to copy and paste.
3. Your `import`s are too broad. It's much preferable to use the `from x import y,z` syntax to avoid polluting the global namespace with everything from these libraries.
4. This comment

   ```
   #You can skip this part and read from the function
   ```

   is completely inscrutable. What do you mean? Who can skip? How do they skip? What part is being skipped?
5. The code for detecting the weekday should be replaced with a call to  `n = now.isoweekday()` This makes `day_name` and `l` completely unnecessary.
6. Of course `n` is a horrible name for the variable. variable names should describe what they're used for.
7. Why do you have both `now` and `Date` that are the same thing? I don't thnk `now` even needs to be a `datetime` since you're only using it for the day of the week.
8. Instead of `date_DD = str(Date)[8:11]` use `Date.day`. No sense converting to a `str` when the date already has what you need. This also removes the need for the `int` call.
9. `day_to_book = (n+5)%7` produces a number from `0` to `6` inclusive. Why are you testing for `7`?
10. All these `if day_to_book` clauses are similar. Don't repeat yourself. Look at the code that's common, put what's different in a data structure, and you can really improve things.
11. Similarly for the `find_element_by_css_selector` and then click. Don't repeat the same code or exactly the same code.
12. The email and password should be in a config file that gets read, the path to the credential file should be a param or from the environment somehow. Never put credentials in your code.